# How to connect old hard drive with usb port?

Tags: hard-drive, usb

I have seagate barracuda 7200.7.
I want to connect it with usb port.
What device do i need for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either a USB enclosure or a USB-to-PATA/SATA adapter.