# How do I transfer data from desktop to Laptop ?

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect old hard drive with usb port?](https://superuser.com/questions/214046/how-to-connect-old-hard-drive-with-usb-port)

I am travelling & taking my desktop's 500 GB Hard Disk ( with data & OS ) with me. Once I reach my destination I will be buying a Laptop there & want to transfer the data from my desktop's HDD to Laptop's HDD.

Without an access to desktop there, how do I transfer data from my desktop's HDD to Laptop's HDD ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Get yourself an external hard drive chassis with USB connector.

Comment: An external hard drive chassis is the way to go.  The ones with USB2 are the most common. If your laptop supports eSATA or USB3 then it will be faster to get an enclosure supporting that. Make sure that both laptop and enclosure support it.